# Is this application of a law of large numbers rigorous in this not identically distributed case?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $ \{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a sequence of indipendent random variables  such that $X_t \sim N(u_t, 1)$ for all $t$ where the mean $u_t$ is given by the equation

$$u_t = \theta u_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-1}$$

where $|\theta| < 1$, $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$ for all $t$ and  $\epsilon_t$ is independent from $\epsilon_s$ for all $t \ne s \in \mathbb{N}$. (we can assume a starting value for $u_0$).

Can one apply a law of large numbers of the following type:

**Theorem** (law of large numbers):
Let  $ \{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a sequence of indipendent random variables with standard deviation $\sigma_t$ and let $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  \sigma_t / t = 0$  then $$S_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n X_i \overset{p}{\to}  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n E[ X_i] $$

to obtain that

$$   S_n \overset{p}{\to} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \left[ u_0 \sum_{i=0}^n \theta^i + \epsilon_0 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \theta^i + \epsilon_1 \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \theta^i + \dots + \epsilon_{n-1} \right]   $$

and since by an analogous law of large numbers

$$  \epsilon_0 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \theta^i + \epsilon_1 \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \theta^i + \dots + \epsilon_{n-1} \overset{p}{\to} 0 $$

we conclude that

$$ S_n \overset{p}{\to} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}  u_0 \sum_{i=0}^n \theta^i =  \frac{u_0}{1-\theta} $$

Is this reasoning rigorous? if not, can it be made so?

Comment: Isn't your mean $u_t$ a random variable (since $\epsilon_{t-1}$ is random)? It's then not really clear what you mean by $X_t \sim N(u_t,1)$ (...since this notation typically is used for deterministic (non-random) means).

Comment: @saz Yes humm this is one of the reason I was wondering if the derivation was rigorous. What I suppose is meant by $X_t  \sim N(u_t,1)$ is $X_t | \epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-1}, \dots, \epsilon_1 \sim N(u_t,1)$. That is we condition (or assume) we know the realizations $\epsilon_t$. Thank you for your question! let me know if you have other ideas

Comment: So that application is not rigorous.  But,it can be done by considering $L_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-u_i)$, now you can take the mean and variance of $L_n$ and note that for $k>0$: $$ E[(X_i-u_i)(X_{i+k}-u_{i+k})] = E[E[(X_i-u_i)(X_{i+k}-u_{i+k})|X_i,u_i,u_{i+k}]]$$ Now assuming that $X_{i+k}$ is conditionally independent of the past, given $u_{i+k}$, we can get the above expectation is 0, which simplifies the calculation of $Var(L_n)$, and by Markov/Chebyshev we get $L_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Comment: @Michael Nice thank you!,  Could you expand a bit on the last part of your comment? from "now assuming"

Comment: You need to show, for $k>0$,  $$E[(X_i-u_i)(X_{i+k}-u_{i+k})|X_i, u_i, u_{i+k}]=0$$ and then write a corresponding expression for $Var(L_n)$.

Comment: @Michael doesn't $E[(X_i-u_i)(X_{i+k}-u_{i+k})|X_i, u_i, u_{i+k}]=u_i u_{i+k}$?

Comment: @saz Once we define $Y_n := X_n + \mu_n$ with $X_n \sim N(0,1)$ and apply the derivation of the question to the sequence $S_n := \sum_{i=0}^n Y_i$ would everything be rigorous then? In other words was your observation the only contentious one or can you see others in the subsequent steps?

Comment: @Monolite : No, how do you arrive at that?

Comment: @Michael By making a mistake, I have since fixed it. Thank you again